# Is it legal to work remotely in the UK for a non-UK based company?

Tags: uk, work, standard-visitor-visas

Assuming a non-EU citizen is visiting the UK on a Standard Visitor Visa (or entered the UK without a visa, if their nationality doesn't require one), can they work remotely for a foreign company? If so, what are the rules for it?

We already have a great answer by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/where-can-i-travel-for-prolonged-periods-of-time-while-legally-working-remotely/45492#45492), but it contains a lot of information which has recently been updated, so it's best to have a separate question.

Comment: Gayot Fow updated his answer only five days ago and wrote that his answer is not affected by the recent changes.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it still contains quite a lot of information that is hard to read through. A simple yes-no answer on a dedicated question is better.

Comment: A difficult to read or poor answer to another question with the same content probably doesn't justify to ask a duplicate question. The question stays the same.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The suggested duplicate is way too broad and the respective answer there is neither visible as first answer, nor does its main text seem to reflect all changes completely, even though the A is recently updated. This Q is well on-topic and has been asked by a mod who should know what they are doing.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo also see: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3638/a-friendly-reminder-that-duplicates-should-be-the-same-question-not-different-q

Comment: @mts Having a little diamond by one's name doesn't make somebody infallible. Your other reasons are good.

Comment: @mts I would also concider the other question too broad, but noone has suggested to close it because of that and both the question and many of the only partial answers have for some reason received a substantial number of upvotes. The community seem to disagree. Being a mod does not mean that Jonathan can't ask a question which should be concidered closed.

Comment: It's worth adding that the suggested dupe asks entirely different question (for list of countries that you can legally work remotely from), and possibly is too broad itself. This question is specific to just UK.

Comment: The problem is, the answer to this question will always be "Yes, to a point..".  Immigration is fully aware that probably most visitors will engage with their overseas job during their visit.  Otherwise, no one who could afford to visit the UK would ever be allowed in ;).  What they don't want is people residing there part time by running out the clock every 6 months.

Comment: @Johns-305 do you mean "yes, to a point when you get caught"? There is a big difference between the legality of something, and how likely it is that it will be enforced. Like in this case, while it's generally speaking not legal to do, it's also nearly impossible to implement, and the chances that you will get caught are almost non-existent unless someone will tip the Home Office.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul You're missing the point.  A genuine Visitor who engages with their employer is still a Visitor.  There is a fuzzy line where you start to appear more like a resident.  It's where you fall on this spectrum that Immigration needs to determine.  It's not about getting caught since they know Visitors are going to do it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer [UK Immigration Rules, Appendix V, Part 4](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#part-v4-eligibility-requirements-for-visitors-standard).  Specifically sections 4.2, 4.5 and 4.7.

Section 4.2 (a) & (b) - The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor...(a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and (b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home; and

Section 4.5 (f) - "The applicant must not intend to work in the UK, which includes the following...(f)providing goods and services"

Section 4.7 - "The applicant must not receive payment from a UK source for any activities undertaken in the UK".

Interpret them as you will but as 4.5 and 4.7 are somewhat contradictory, this question can't be answered conclusively except by a UK Immigration Officer.

Other members, who may appear to comment or Answer, indicate 4.7 is what would lead to a Yes answer for this question.

Note: These are admissibility rules, taxes are a completely different subject.

Comment: I am split on this - and, as you pointed out, tend to think that Section 4.7 would lead to a Yes answer.

Comment: @AleksG Realistically, they have no reason to care if you're doing a job you already have.  If 4.2 and 4.7 are satisfied, you're not taking a job from a local, which is what they are really looking out for, understandably.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.