# Can I have a same sex marriage to my partner who is overseas?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, weddings

I hope to seek some advice on marrying my partner who is from South Africa. We have been together 2 years and she has visited me twice in the UK where I am born and lived my whole life. Am I allowed to marry her now whilst she is here but she is only on a visitor visa and I want to surprise her.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/112043/6188

Comment: Beware that same-sex marriage across countries might put both of you in a difficult position in the case of divorce: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/26719/9236

Comment: @SJuan76 While interesting I don't think that link is relevant here as the OP is a UK citizen and wants to get married in the UK.  That link referred to the catch-22 situation of the marriage not being recognized where they live and not being residents of where they were married.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I would like to take her to a register office and marry. Just a bit tricky that she is here in the UK on a visitor visa so I don’t want any problems for her to occur after she leaves.

Answer (score 3):

No. Marrying, registering a civil partnership, or giving notice of marriage or civil partnership is not permitted for those visiting the UK on a Standard Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa
Edit: this [Can I marry in the UK while on a standard visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89701/can-i-marry-in-the-uk-while-on-a-standard-visitor-visa) provides a huge amount of detail on the topic